# Can I make history not print any timestamps for commands that were run before I enabled that option?

Tags: bash, command-history

If you run `history`, it outputs the current date before commands that were run before I enabled timestamps, is there anyway I can make it ignore that?

For example, if my `.bash_history` looks like this:

```
1  +2016-01-30 16:54:10 cd /tmp
2  +2016-01-30 16:54:10 wine *exe
3  +2016-01-30 16:54:10 grep...
4  +2016-01-30 16:54:10 sed.....
5  +2016-01-30 16:52:20 history
```

I want it not to output the dates on commands 1-4 because that's just the current date, and I hadn't enabled `$HISTTIMEFORMAT` when these commands were run.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.bash_history` file doesn't look like that, only the `history` display. The format in the file is `#` and a single number (seconds since epoch) on a separate line. And for entries stored (and thus read) without such a time value, the display shows when your current shell read the history, usually when the shell started, not actually the current time.

If you edit the file to insert `#` and the number for a known time before each entry that doesn't have a real `#seconds` value, you could then set up an alias or function (or even script) to `sed` (or `awk` etc) that (formatted) time out of the display. 
And (at least on the versions I have to hand, 4.1.2 and 4.3.11) if you edit the file to insert `#0` specifically, it apparently considers that invalid and displays `??` (two question marks) *instead of* the formatted time, which isn't what you asked for but might be close enough for government work.

To save time (and mistakes) you could do this edit automatically with

```
perl -ni.bak 'if /^#/ print $_.<> else print "#seconds".$/.$_' .bash_history
```